# Powershell Loop and Replace (reading from text file)

Tags: powershell

I converted an Excel to CSV and I'm trying to clean up all the garbage characters (non-english) using a `ForEach-Object` loop with a replace.

As I find characters I want to remove I just pipe them together.

My code line is starting to get very long. Is there a more efficient way of doing this without having all the pipes? I'm using Powershell ISE.

Example:

```
(Get-Content C:\Users\myexcel.csv) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '\W',' '} |`
ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'ÿ',' '} | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'À',' '} |`
ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'Ô',' '}  | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'õ',' '}  |`
ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'ý',' '} > C:\Users\newfile.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

You can chain the replace and no need to pipe constantly.

E.G.

```
(Get-Content "C:\Users\myexcel.csv") -replace '[ÿÀõÔý]',' ' | Out-file "C:\Users\newfile.csv"
```

The `[` and `]` denote a character set, matching any of the characters inside it.

Comment: I would use this instead, `'[ÀÿÔýõ\\W]'`. This includes \W as well.

Comment: `\\W` inside brackets will match \ and W as separate characters, not as a sequence

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with foreign characters?  You can specify a different encoding with export-csv.  You can chain multiple -replaces.  You don't need backquotes to continue lines.  Pipes do that by themselves.  You can continue with a comma too.  I prefer set-content to '>' or out-file.  Out-file defaults to unicode encoding.  If it's a different file, you don't need parentheses to load the whole file first.

```
Get-Content C:\Users\myexcel.csv | 
  ForEach { $_ -replace '\W',' ' -replace 'ÿ',' ' -replace 'À',' ' -replace 'Ô',
  ' ' -replace 'õ',' ' -replace 'ý',' ' } | 
  Set-Content C:\Users\newfile.csv
```

There's the or "|" style of regex too:

```
Get-Content C:\Users\myexcel.csv | 
  ForEach { $_ -replace '\W|ÿ|À|Ô|õ|ý',' ' } | 
  Set-Content C:\Users\newfile.csv
```